# What is meant by interval notation in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am reading a version of the mean-value theorem and it goes as follows:

[image]

What is meant by, 'the interval $[x,x+s]$'?

Comment: Try with a simple example : $x=1$ and $s=\dfrac 1 2$.

Comment: This doesn't help, since the OP's problem concerns dimensions greater than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this notation is meant to describe the set
$$ [x,x+s]:=\{x+\lambda s:\lambda\in[0,1]\}.$$
More general-looking: for any $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, one sets
$$ [x,y]:=\{x+\lambda (y-x):\lambda\in[0,1]\},$$
which is the convex hull of the set $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Ill accept this when it allows me to.

Comment: But such thing cannot be a member of the open set S as asserted by the theorem.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes, that's what I just thought as well. But this is probably an error in the notation and it should say $[x,x+s]\subset \mathcal S$. The rest wouldn't make sense otherwise, or am I missing something?

Comment: Check the errata for the book.  If it is not there point out the mistake to the author or publisher.